# Online website resources removed, name changed or temporarily unavailable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got an issue with the `asp.net mvc` website I'm building in visual studio 2015.

The issue is that it works perfectly fine on my local host but it stops working on my web domain and I get errors below:

> `Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.`
>   `Description: HTTP 404.` 
>   `The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`
>   `Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.`
>
> `Requested URL: /Enterprise/Group`

Whereas these files are present here.

Comment: Do you have some code example of your upload Action? Have you tried to use full path?

Comment: When you get this error ?

Comment: Some of the urls are working fine in web hosting e.g ~/Career/Index whereas others are not working ~/Enterprise/Group .... I dont know what is the reason behind

Comment: #miraj my web site is working file on my local hot machine but it is not woeking on my web hosting

Comment: If files are uploaded correctly, then you must wander if your server defines root (`/`) in the right place. Have a look at your `.htaccess` and share the relevant parts with us.

Comment: Some of the file urls are working correctly. So i dont know where should i check paths